# Java - nextLine(); within a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I have a switch statement acting as a menu, in this I am trying to read the users input. Currently I am using `variable=in.next();` and this works. However it will only read one word and at points the user may need to enter more, so I tried using `variable=in.nextLine();`, which compiles, but when I run the program, I select my choice from the menu, and it skips the reading in and return to the menu.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
name=in.nextLine();
```

and

```
String choice = in.nextLine();
```

This should be in the constructor, and at the top of runApp.

That way, you're not leaving the new line in the buffer (where it will be used for e.g. `dp`).

You should have:

```
dp=in.nextLine();
```

as described in your question.

Comment: I still have the same problem, unless I've misunderstood your answer, it's very likely since I haven't been programming for very long.

Comment: @Ben, I tested it with your code.  I had to comment out the calls to methods you didn't include.  Can you post your current code (you can edit the question and use the 101 button for formatting)?

Comment: can't get the editor to work properly, hope you can make sense of that.

i have put
`dp=in.nextLine();`

as you can see but that is what gives me the error.

Comment: @Ben, right, but you didn't change the `String choice` line at the top.

Comment: done that, it compiles but now i'm getting this when I type start and hit enter to bring up the menu:

`java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
String index out of range: 0 (in java.lang.String)`

Comment: forgot to say which line it was on, so sorry

`        ch=choice.charAt(0);`

thanks for the help so far, it is very much appreicated

Comment: @Ben, you need to do the same thing for `name` in the constructor.  Before I didn't realize `runApp` wasn't the first input code.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to strip the newline character `\n` from the user input or assume it's there in your switch statement.

Pretty much because you decided to use nextLine() the user input to the computer will look like this

```
 f\n
```

So just compare the strings accordingly!

Answer (score -1):

Switch selector can be only integer, short, char or enum. String cannot be used as a switch selector.

If I understood you correctly you would like to control your flow using words entered by user. If you have predefined list of words I'd suggest you to use enum:

enum Words {
    start, stop, beep,
}

Now user enters a word beep. You can say:

```
Words command = Words.valueOf();
///
switch (command) {
    case start: /* start something */ break;
    case stop: /* stop something */ break;
    case beep: /* beep!!! */ break;
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown command " + command);
}
```

Comment: See my comment to vic's answer.  It wouldn't compile.

Answer (score -1):

OK I think I am too inept at Java and have put my question badly.

When I take the users input it takes only 1 word, I want it to take everything they put basically, and when I use nextLine, this just skips the reading and takes me back to selecting a choice.

Comment: How did you get a simple link to a dropbox file?

Comment: right click the file in explorer, dropbox, copy public link.

any chance of some help with the problem? :P